# Authenticate Zimbra Domain with Zentyal Server (using External LDAP)

Tags: authentication, ldap, zimbra

I have installed and configured Zimbra 8.5 and Zentyal 4.0. Now, I am trying to let Zimbra Authenticate form the Zentyal LDAP server.  The base Domain name is **mycompany.local**. Can anyone please give a better idea on that the below steps means, we those are giving step by step instructions but the place where I need to change it to my values is where I Struggle. I keep getting **Simple Bind Failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE**. I port given here is 390 but it is unresponsive but it works fine giving the above error at port 389/

This is What I have found on Zentyal Forums, but the User who posted it is no longer active.

[Link to Post](https://forum.zentyal.org/index.php?topic=18594.0)

To summarize everything. Short instruction on how to setup LDAP Autoprovisioning in Zimbra 8 from Zentyal 3+
Create a group "mail" in Zentyal as you, probably do not want all the users to authenticate, but only in the group "mail".
In the Zimbra Admin Web Interface go to Configure -> Domains -> right click on the domain that you want to assign with zentyal and select Configure Authetication, choose External LDAP.
Ldap://**{domain_name or ip of Zentyal}**: 390
LDAP filter: (&(|(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))(|(memberof=cn=mail,**{Default Groups DN in Zentyal}**))(uid=%u))
LDAP search base: **{Default Users DN in Zentyal}**
Bind DN: **{root DN from zentyal}**
Bind password: **{Zentyal root password}**

**My Values: for my Zentyal Server**

Base DN
DC=mycompany,DC=local

Default Users DN
CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local

Default Groups DN
CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local

Ldap://**mycompany.local**: 390
LDAP filter: (&(|(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))(|(memberof=cn=mail,**Users**))(uid=%u))
LDAP search base: **mycompany


**Bind DN: **mycompany**

Bind password: mypassword****

The Error

```
com.zimbra.cs.ldap.LdapException: LDAP error:  - unable to get connection: Simple Bind Failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
ExceptionId:qtp509886383-531:https://192.168.2.203:7071/service/admin/soap/CheckAuthConfigRequest:1416831184639:521014fe06c36a62
Code:ldap.LDAP_ERROR
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.LdapException.LDAP_ERROR(LdapException.java:90)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapException.mapToLdapException(UBIDLdapException.java:74)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapException.mapToExternalLdapException(UBIDLdapException.java:84)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapContext.mapToLdapException(UBIDLdapContext.java:225)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapContext.getConnection(UBIDLdapContext.java:199)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapContext.(UBIDLdapContext.java:171)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapClient.getExternalContextImpl(UBIDLdapClient.java:106)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.LdapClient.getExternalContext(LdapClient.java:169)
    at com.zimbra.cs.account.ldap.LdapProvisioning.ldapAuthenticate(LdapProvisioning.java:5113)
    at com.zimbra.cs.account.ldap.LdapProvisioning.checkAuthConfig(LdapProvisioning.java:5168)
    at com.zimbra.cs.service.admin.CheckAuthConfig.handle(CheckAuthConfig.java:48)
    at com.zimbra.soap.SoapEngine.dispatchRequest(SoapEngine.java:564)
    at com.zimbra.soap.SoapEngine.dispatch(SoapEngine.java:427)
    at com.zimbra.soap.SoapEngine.dispatch(SoapEngine.java:265)
    at com.zimbra.soap.SoapServlet.doWork(SoapServlet.java:303)
    at com.zimbra.soap.SoapServlet.doPost(SoapServlet.java:213)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.ZimbraServlet.service(ZimbraServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1651)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.RequestStringFilter.doFilter(RequestStringFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.SetHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHeaderFilter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.ETagHeaderFilter.doFilter(ETagHeaderFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.ContextPathBasedThreadPoolBalancerFilter.doFilter(ContextPathBasedThreadPoolBalancerFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.ZimbraQoSFilter.doFilter(ZimbraQoSFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at com.zimbra.cs.servlet.ZimbraInvalidLoginFilter.doFilter(ZimbraInvalidLoginFilter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter.doFilterChain(DoSFilter.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter.doFilter(DoSFilter.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter.doFilter(DoSFilter.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DebugHandler.handle(DebugHandler.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: LDAPException(resultCode=49 (invalid credentials), errorMessage='Simple Bind Failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL', diagnosticMessage='Simple Bind Failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL')
    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:1894)
    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionPool.createConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:988)
    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionPool.getConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:1399)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapOperation$GetConnection.execute(UBIDLdapOperation.java:183)
    at com.zimbra.cs.ldap.unboundid.UBIDLdapContext.getConnection(UBIDLdapContext.java:190)
    ... 57 more
```

after this when I try to Test the Authentication, I gives the Error. I am complete n00b to LDAP so please forgive for obvious Mistake.